# Codeigniter: Trigger a Materialize.Toast using Codeigniter.Session.Flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a login system in Codeigniter, I am also using Materialize CSS.

I would like to trigger a toast if the username/password is not correct.

My Controller with Session.Flashdata

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Incorrect Username and Password');
```

In my login page

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')) : ?>
    <?php echo '<script>Materialize.toast("' .$this->session->flashdata('login_failed'). '", 2000)</script>' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to echo out Materialize.toast() but it is not showing.

Comment: check console for errors. you dont need three php tags for if block

Answer (score 1):

Try this once
$this->session->msg = 'Edited Successfully';